# Asp.NET Core API: Generate a PK of GUID/UUID type to MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am creating a code-first WebAPI using asp.net core. I want to define a table with a **UUID/GUID Pk of type BINARY(16)**, this table preferably being auto generated similar to the auto_increment where you plug in the rest of the column and the Db auto-fills the pk/id.

I have tried creating a trigger for the field after Db generation to fill the Pk with a UUID but it does not allow me to use UUID().

Anyway, here is a sample of the table i want to populate:
DbContext.cs

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<Customers>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.CustomerId)
                .HasName("PRIMARY");

            entity.ToTable("customers");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.CustomerId)
                .HasName("customer_id_UNIQUE")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.CustomerId)
                .HasColumnName("customer_id")
                .HasColumnType("BINARY(16)");
}
```

Using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql if it makes any difference.

I know that there is a GUID() function in .NET but i'm not sure how to make MySql would auto generate it.
I have tried to come up with many solutions but to no end, trying to use stored procedures, ValueGenerator, etc..

Please offer any suggestions, codes or pointers that you might know as this is very frustrating to me as I would say i'm a beginner.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Add DataAnnotations to your column

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
```

in your migration you should change your CreateTable to add the defaultValueSQL property to your column :

```
CustomerId = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true, defaultValueSql: "NEWID()")
```

or fluent API :

```
entity.Property(x => x.CustomerId).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
```

Manually setting in sql server :
[image]

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. Just to make sure, does this apply to MySql server too?

Comment: Try using UUID() instead of newid()
and check for annotations in my sql.
keep [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] if you dont want auto increment

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Although hopeful but it failed: "Expression of generated column 'customer_id' contains a disallowed function: uuid" I guess MySql does not like generating UUIDs on the spot

Comment: If you can, would you suggest a way to convert Guid() to binary. I think i'll have to give up and feed it manually

Comment: Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var bytes = guid.ToByteArray();

Comment: Thank you very much. Hope the best for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<Customers>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.CustomerId)
                .HasName("PRIMARY")
                .HasComputedColumnSql("SELECT UUID()");

            entity.ToTable("customers");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.CustomerId)
                .HasName("customer_id_UNIQUE")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.CustomerId)
                .HasColumnName("customer_id")
                .HasColumnType("BINARY(16)");
        }
```

Comment: Fails due to: Expression of generated column 'customer_id' contains a disallowed function: uuid.

Comment: If you can, would you suggest a way to convert Guid() to binary. I think i'll have to give up and feed it manually

Comment: Thinking about it, would you know how to insert triggers into mysql from the asp.net code?